# XML parsing using xmlsequence extract function (PL/SQL)

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, namespaces

I am trying to parse an XML file using the following query (used in a cursor function):
[image]

The problem I am facing is that my XML file contains 2 Namespaces, something like this:
[image]

I could work it out in case there is only one xmlns, by defining p_urn to be the value of the xmlns.

How I can achieve this with the extract function in the case I have 2 xmlns?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your raw data, query and expected result as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this by skipping or wild-carding some or all of the elements:

```
-- with only p_urn_1 - wildcard inner default namespace
select extractvalue(value(p), '/*:Header/*:VersionInfo/*:Version/text()', p_urn_1) as version
from table (xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(pp_xml), '/Document/*:Header', p_urn_1))) p;

-- with only p_urn_2 - wildcard outer default namespace
select extractvalue(value(p), '/Header/VersionInfo/Version/text()', p_urn_2) as version
from table (xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(pp_xml), '/*:Document/Header', p_urn_2))) p;

-- with only p_urn_2 - skip outer element
select extractvalue(value(p), '/Header/VersionInfo/Version/text()', p_urn_2) as version
from table (xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(pp_xml), '//Header', p_urn_2))) p;

-- without either p_urn_1 or p_urn_2 - wildcard everything
select extractvalue(value(p), '/*:Header/*:VersionInfo/*:Version/text()') as version
from table (xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(pp_xml), '/*:Document/*:Header'))) p;

-- with both p_urn_1 and p_urn_2 - single wildcard (safe-ish)
select extractvalue(value(p), '/Header/VersionInfo/Version/text()', p_urn_2) as version
from table (xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(pp_xml), '/Document/*:Header', p_urn_1))) p;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=951125009c38526ebebdacf5f5c06554)

But you are using several deprecated functions. You should look at XMLQuery and XMLTable, which allow multiple namespaces; though providing the namespaces dynamically isn't easy.